# Prevent manual scrolling to the "preselected" folder being required when using `TSelectDirectoryDialog`

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

When I'm setting the `InitialDir` property of `TSelectDirectoryDialog` the folder will be "selected" but I still have to scroll to it if it's below the currently visible area.

Is there a way I can make `TSelectDirectoryDialog` not to start at the beginning? Or is it possible to use a different dialog to select an existing folder the behaves the way I'm looking for?

Currently I'm using it on a Windows 7 64bit system.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this blog post:https://blog.dummzeuch.de/2016/05/03/fixing-selectdirectory-function/  It's for Delphi, but should be applicable to Lazarus, too.  Btw. your title could do with "being required" after "folder".  As written, it is not what you are meaning to ask.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look...  and thanks for the suggestion for the title!

Answer (score 1):

For me (Laz 1.8.4, Win 10) the TSelectDirectorydialog immediately goes to the InitialDir by default. The dialog looks like a FileOpen dialog, though. If you prefer the old dialog with the treeview alone you should turn the option ofOldStyleDialog ON and ofEnableSizing OFF (the latter is due to a bug in Windows).

Comment: I'm on Laz 1.6.x and Win 7, there I still have the "old" Tree view as a default. I'll have to update some time in the future anyway 'cause some relevant Laz bugs are not corrected in my version, I'll let you know if it works...